# How to assign a boolean value of an JSF selectBooleanCheckbox as parameter to a java script function?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have the following example in my jsf xhtml page:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.fieldvalue1}" onchange="updateJsFunction(this);"/>
```

The parameter "this" for the js function "updateJsFunction" doesn´t includes the value of the selectBooleanCheckbox, which was selected or deselected.

Is there a way to assign the value of an selectBooleanCheckbox in a java script function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to work on the DOM.
The 'this' you refer to is the generated HTML checkbox, you must see if it has the attribute 'checked'.
If you use jQuery it would be something like:

```
jQuery(this).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `onchange="updateJsFunction(this);"` with `onchange="updateJsFunction(event);"`

And then do what ever you want with `$(event.target)` (if you use jQuery) or inspect the `event.target` with js